# YUM command on Mobaxterm, windows

Tags: yum, file-not-found, mobaxterm

I am new to that area,

I have installed Mobaexterm and try to run the YUM as part of some command.
It says that the YUM command is not found

Apperantly I need to install also a specific package to do that.
If I had a UNIX env, the command I would have run through the mobaxterm's terminal would look like:
"yum install yum-utils.noarch"

Does anyone know to tell what command windows env?

Answer (score 0):

In MobaXterm you should use `apt-get`

```
apt-get install somepackage
```

This software is Debian based and use these utils to manage packages.

Answer (score 0):

'yum' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

For windows use this

pip install ansible-core